# How to insert special character like £ with price like (£ 2,000) in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to  insert record to my database table with having data like (£ 2,000).

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it currently an int? Store it as a varchar with UTF8, and you should be able to do that just fine.

Comment: Or just store the integer, then display that special char when you needed it in the `html`

Comment: aas qirel mentioned .....check your db if that field is set to int if it is alter it to string

Comment: I did this, but still values are  not inserting to field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the table as:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

> And make sure the datatype of the column is varchar.

Also if you plan to output that data in a webpage you can to insert [HTML Entities for Currencies](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp) in the db and then when you output it in a webpage, the HTML will render the entities as regular characters.

[It works for me](https://imgur.com/a/1ZOzm)

Comment: I do not want to display this at webpage, i only need this to insert to database as it is.

Comment: Make sure the column char set is utf8 and the column type is varchar. To do that run `DESCRIBE <table_name>;` in the mysql shell.

Comment: Yes, the column type is varchar and collation is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: yes, I also did that from shell and it worked for me as well. But when i tried to insert through PHP code it don't insert to table.

Comment: I gave you wrong SQL code, sorry. I'm happy you found a way to do it. Please mark my question as accepted if you want and give an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that changing the column type and collation type did this.I have changed the column type to varchar and collation to utf-8 and it worked.